# Method on user model to check variable on another table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a user model, and I want to check if a user has been assigned a mentor.

```
public function mentorapplication()
{
    return $this->hasMany(mentorApplication::class, 'user_id');
}

public function mentorAssigned()
    {
          return ($this->mentorapplication()->status == "counsellorAssigned");
    }
```

when I call `$user->mentorAssigned()` in tinker I get an undefined property for status.

Any ideas?

Comment: You've defined a one-to-many relationship here.  You could have multiple related entities that have a status...

Comment: `$this->mentorapplication()` is a `Collection`, not a single `mentorApplication`, and `Collection`s don't have a `status` attribute. `$this->mentorapplication()->first()` would work, but perhaps confirm your logic. Also, try to follow naming conventions, `MentorApplication` for class name, `mentorApplication` for method name.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here. Firstly, your relationship is has-many, which is one-to-many. When you try to use the relationship you should expect a `Collection` to be returned, rather than a single entity. Therefore trying to access the `->status` property on returned collection won't work.

Secondly, when you're trying to access the relationship like this:

```
$this->mentorapplication()
```

You will get a `HasMany` instance, which would allow you to chain on more constraints to the query, just like `->where(...)`, or `->orderBy(...)`. You would need to use something like `->get()` or `->first()` to actually run the query and get the results you're after. You can omit the `()` here and Laravel will load the relation for you, returning your collection:

```
$this->mentorapplication
```

Now, I don't know exactly what it is you're trying to achieve, but say for instance you wanted to see if at least *one* of the `mentorApplication` objects assigned to the user has a status of `counsellorAssigned`, you could do something like this:

```
public function mentorAssigned()
{
    foreach ($this->mentorapplication as $mentorapplication) {
        if ($mentorapplication->status == 'counsellorAssigned') {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Or you could use Laravel's `Collection` methods to help you rather than just doing a loop here. There are many approaches you could take so I will just leave it there.